# What node(s) does Ethereum broadcast a transaction first? How is it determined?

Tags: transactions, dapp-development, nodes, decentralization

When I as a user make a transaction, where or what node(s) does it get sent to **first**? How does  an Ethereum node, in **terms of implementation details**, determine that? Does it send a new transaction to, say, 1 **random** or multiple random node? Or to a certain one(s) that meet a certain criteria?

Or to the all nodes in the world?

Also, does an Ethereum node keep a list of **all the nodes in the world,** dynamically, in RAM, and periodically refreshe it? Or does it do it at startup and then simply works with that, never refreshing a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I as a user make a transaction, where or what node(s) does it get sent to first?

The nodes your node knows about - its connected peers. This will be a subset of the entire network. (Explained in more detail later.)

> How does an Ethereum node, in terms of implementation details, determine that?

Ethereum uses its own set of networking and peer-discovery protocols (under the [devp2p](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p) umbrella).

When your client node joins the network it has a hard-coded set of boot nodes that it knows about and talks to. (The Geth client bootnodes can be found in [`bootnodes.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/bootnodes.go))

Having completed the initial boot from these bootnodes, it then uses a peer discovery protocol (part of devp2p) to develop a larger picture of the network. (Peer discovery is based around DHT/Kademlia, and is detailed [here](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/discv4.md).)

> Does it send a new transaction to, say, 1 random or multiple random node?

It sends the transaction to all known peers.

> Also, does an Ethereum node keep a list of all the nodes in the world, dynamically, in RAM, and periodically refreshe it?

As mentioned above, Ethereum uses a Kademlia-like DHT-based protocol. ([Kademlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) is widely used in networking, it's not Ethereum specific.)

A node keeps its own version of a distributed hash table (DHT) detailing its set of neighbouring nodes, in memory. If it receives a newer version of the hash table from one of its peers, it updates its own.

"Neighbouring nodes" are defined in such a way that a node won't know about the *entire* network, just a subset. (The implementation details of how to calculate neighbouring nodes, and how many of them there are, is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/discv4.md#kademlia-table).)